# Google API v3 .Net client Unauthorized client or scope in request

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-oauth

I'm getting the error message "Unauthorized client or scope in request." When the following code executes.  If I remove the `.User = myUserEmail` parameter I get a "Insufficient Permission [403]" error message.  If I had to guess, I would guess that the issue is the .user parameter I'm using.  But, I don't what I'm doing wrong there.  I'm using the email address associated with the Google Account I normally use to login to Google Analytics.

```
    Private myClientEmail As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("clientEmail").ToString()
    Private myP12Path As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("p12Path").ToString()
    Private myP12Password As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("p12Password").ToString()
    Private myUserEmail As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("userEmail").ToString()
    Private myApplicationName As String = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("applicationName").ToString()

    Dim scopes As IList(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
    scopes.Add("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly")

    Dim certificate As X509Certificate2 = New X509Certificate2(myP12Path, myP12Password, X509KeyStorageFlags.Exportable)

    Dim credential As ServiceAccountCredential = New ServiceAccountCredential(New ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(myClientEmail) With {
                                                                                .Scopes = scopes,
                                                                                .User = myUserEmail
                                                                              }.FromCertificate(certificate))

    Dim service As AnalyticsService = New AnalyticsService(New BaseClientService.Initializer() With {
                                                                                    .HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                                                                                    .ApplicationName = myApplicationName
                                                                                })

    Dim profileId As String = "ga:12345678"
    Dim startDate As String = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim endDate As String = DateTime.Today.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
    Dim metrics As String = "ga:visits"
    Dim request As DataResource.GaResource.GetRequest = service.Data.Ga.Get(profileId, startDate, endDate, metrics)
    request.Dimensions = "ga:date"
    Dim data As GaData = request.Execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in my ways...

Somewhere along the lines I inadvertently changed the scope to the "drive.readonly".  When I'm trying to work with the "analytics.readonly".